# Converting LIDAR based measurement to UTM coordinate?

Tags: lidar, utm, spherical-geometry, matlab

I have lidar based measurement with azimuth elevation and range, I would like to convert this data to UTM coordinate. I know the position of the lidar in UTM coordinate system, so I developed the following code in Matlab

```
LOS = [cosd(ele)*sind(azi); cosd(ele)*cosd(azi); sind(ele)]
% 

R1 = [cosd(yaw), -sind(yaw), 0 ;...
      sind(yaw), cosd(yaw) , 0;...
      0     , 0      , 1];

R2 = [1,  0     ,  0     ;...
      0,  cosd(pitch),  sind(pitch); ...
      0, -sind(pitch),  cosd(pitch) ];

R3 = [cosd(roll)  , 0 , -sind(roll);...
      0       , 1 , 0     ;...
      sind(roll) , 0 , cosd(roll) ];

LOS2 = [LOS'*RR]

x=LOS2(1)*range+OFF2(1)
y=LOS2(2)*range+OFF2(2)
z=LOS2(3)*range+OFF2(3)
```

But I am not quiet sure that the rotation matrix is good. Am I gooing in the right path?

Comment: A lot depends on how the instrument providing the roll-pitch-yaw values (an external IMU?) defines roll-pitch-yaw. There are a bunch pf ways to turn roll-pitch-yaw values into a rotation matrix, depending on which order you apply the rotations, which angle you plug into which rotation matrix, and the per-axis handness of your coordinate system.

So you're not on a wrong path, but I'm not sure there's a way to know if you're on the right path without more information, such as the rotation order definition of your IMU.